# I can't install the CAR package on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Tags: r, r-car

I have Version 0.99.467 – © 2009-2015 for R Studio and cannot install the CAR package on my Mac OS X 10.8.5.

I have tried the install.packages("car") in the console, as well as manually importing the zip files from the CRAN website: car_2.0-26.tgz / car_2.0-25.tgz

I have also tried to install the older sources from the car archive although none of these will work.

I need this package for my statistics assignment and am having no luck in loading it.

Comment: *cannot install* and *am having no luck* are not meaningful problem descriptions. What **specifically** is not working for you? Do you get error messages? If  so, what are they **exactly**? If not, what **exactly** happens when you try to install? We're glad to try and help, but we can't do so if you give us no details with which to work.

Comment: that version of RStudio is pretty old, current stable is 1.1.453, if that was the last time you upgraded R, then you might be having issues because of an outdated R.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the error:

> Loading required package: car
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘quantreg’
>   Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

Try installing the quantreg package before you run the car package.